# Calculating x and y coordinates from curvilinear orthogonal coordinates.

Tags: vector-analysis, coordinate-systems

We have a curvilinear orthogonal coordinate system defined with $u=xy$, $v=\frac{x^2 - y^2}{2}$, $z=z$.

First, calculate x and y.
For them, I got $x=\sqrt{\frac{-2v\pm2\sqrt{v^2-u^2}}{2}}$ and $y=u/x$.

Then we have to calculate the Lamé coeffitiens, and after that the divergence.

I wonder if there is another method to define the x and y coordinates, or if I have miscalculated something; because with these expressions, I'm afraid I cannot carry out all the calculations.

Comment: I realized that this is some kind of a parabolic coordinate system, but I am still stuck with it.

Comment: Or, I wonder if the calculation of Lamé coeffitients means derivating by x and y and z. Because that way I'd get back those from paraboloid coordinate system. This way though, derivating the x and y by u and v is a bit complicated.

Comment: For problems like this, instead of differentiating the ugly expressions for the inverse map, it can be easier to invert the Jacobian of the forward map and work with that. In this case it looks like the Lamé coefficients will simplify nicely without having to express the partial derivatives in terms of $u$ and $v$ first.

Comment: Wow, it seems I missed the Jacobian. I'll try to look it up, but just in case, could you please find me a useful link? I appreciate your help!

Comment: The Jacobian matrix is just the matrix of partial derivatives of $u$, $v$ and $z$ w/r $x$, $y$ and $z$. Inverting it will give you the partial derivatives in the other direction, still expressed in terms of $x$, $y$ and $z$.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much!